# Use Measure as a slicer without Unpivot Data

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure, slicers

I have to re-create the following sample view where % Expected Payments and % Expected Accounts are division calculations.

[Requested View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/084VJ.png)

At present, I created another table like this:

Attribute   Value
% Expected Payments 1
% Expected Accounts 2

In my data, I added two columns to hold this information and did unpivot like this:

[My edited data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0rWb.png)

I linked both the tables with the column Attribute and used the below DAX to do the calculations:

Measure = IF(CONTAINS(Table1,Table1[Attribute],"% Expected Payments"),DIVIDE(SUM(Table1[Payments]),SUM(Table1[Estimated Payments])),IF(CONTAINS(Table1,Table1[Attribute],"% Expected Accounts"),DIVIDE(SUM(Table1[Accounts]),SUM(Table1[Estimated Accounts])),0))

This solution works for me.

However,
I have millions of data and 30 attributes. This solution will increase my data rows to : Millions of Data * 30, which is a lot.
Every month, the data increases in size and I have to store that data in Power-BI Desktop.
Is there any way to achieve the same scenerio without doing the unpivot option in the actual data ? Maybe by creating different measure for each metric and proceeding somehow to get the correct calculation ?

Any help is appreciated.

Please find my sample solution of dummy data for your alteration here :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UydHHYd4iBVDTu7xoWfRoHM3OYC4lgQZ

I am looking forward to getting a solution soon.

Comment: Your images didn’t come through. Can you try uploading those again?

Comment: Hi @GregGalloway, Thanks for checking. I have updated the image links.